# Creating a Redshift database from an RDS PostgreSQL database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis

The job I'm in has a complete AWS setup. We have an Amazon RDS PostgreSQL database that we are wanting to move into an Amazon Redshift datahub.

The thing is, I'm completely lost on where to go.  I have Redshift setup, and properly setup on security, but that is where my googling has led me to a wall.

Can you  help me on this? I'm going to be using Kinesis to stream data from our PostgreSQL database to Redshift. Do I have to set up tables to begin the process, or can I just go ahead and do the stream from Kinesis, and that would take the process from there?

Comment: why use kinesis? use aws DMS for this.

Comment: Could you please Edit your question and provide additional information about the streaming component? Are you intending to use this just for the initial population of the database, or as an on-going datasource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to migrate a PostgreSQL database to Redshift, then you can use the [AWS Database Migration Service Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/dms/).

It can do a one-off migration or can perform a continuous migration to keep the databases "in sync".

There should be no need to involve Kinesis for a database migration.

If, however, you wish to continually load data into your Redshift cluster (eg stream data from a website and capture it in Redshift), then you will want to use [Amazon Kinesis Firehose](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/what-is-this-service.html), which can stream directly into Redshift.